# 'ng build --prod' not working after upgrading to Angular 5.2.2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

the app Im working on was at Angular 4.3.4 for the last months and I decided to update it to the most recent version, 5.2.2.

To make things short, when I attempt to build a production with 'ng build --prod' the CLI throws this error at me:

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'ea'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'emakeDecorator' was 
  called in 'Injectable'
  'Injectable' calls 'emakeDecorator'
```

I have tried a lot of things including deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, updating npm and trying version 5.2.0 instead of 5.2.2. Nothing seems to be working.

Does anyone happen to have the same problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it myself. Credit goes to https://github.com/sureshchahal/angular2-adal/issues/23 comment by Gullfaxi.

The problem has something to-do with the AOT compilation, but dont ask me any further on this. I cant explain anything in detail.

However, go to your tsconfig.app.json and add the following line:

```
"paths": { "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"] },
```

Also make sure that in the same file, the module is set to 'es2015'.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Self answer, appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way out of this situation with a slight hampering in performance is by build the app with the below code:

```
ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false.
```

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: I don't think is the best way out but at least might help to easily skip the error until the proper configuration is found and set. That's why I up voted this answer :)